# Primefaces 5.1 : Bar and pie charts display no legends

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, charts

No legends appears in my bar and pie charts.
I tried several arguments for `setLegendPlacement` and `setLegendPosition` methods but it was without results.

Where I went wrong ?

This is my config for the bar chart :

```
 BarChartModel model = new BarChartModel();
 model.setZoom(true);
 model.setLegendPlacement(LegendPlacement.INSIDE);
 model.setLegendPosition("ne");
 model.setAnimate(true);
 model.setMouseoverHighlight(true);
 model.setShowPointLabels(true);

 ChartSeries myChartSeries = new ChartSeries();
 bank.setLabel("myChatSeries");
 for (String key : datas.keys()) {
     bank.set(key, datas.get(key));
 }
 model.addSeries(myChartSeries);

 Axis yAxis = model.getAxis(AxisType.Y);
 yAxis.setLabel(status.name());
 yAxis.setMin(0);
 yAxis.setMax(maxCount+1);
 yAxis.setTickInterval("2");

 Axis xAxis = model.getAxis(AxisType.X);
 xAxis.setTickAngle(-20);
```

This is my config for the pie chart :

```
PieChartModel model = new PieChartModel();

model.setLegendPosition("ne");
model.setLegendPlacement(LegendPlacement.INSIDE);
model.setTitle("Informations général");
model.setMouseoverHighlight(true);
model.setShowDataLabels(true);

model.set("type1", 3);
model.set("type2", 6);
model.set("type3", 8);
```

My stack : java 8, jsf 2.1.28, primefaces 5.1, primefaces-themes 1.0.10

Comment: For a much higher chance of help, consider creating an [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by setting the property `legend.show` to `true` on a hook before drawing :

```
$.jqplot.preDrawHooks.push(function () {
    this.legend.show = true;
});
```

A little trashy hack somehow, Primefaces 5.1 doesn't seem to set this property by default.